# enclosure SSD does not recognized in Ubuntu

Tags: ssd

Goodmorning everyone.

Two weeks ago I had a problem with my SSD on which I had a double partition for Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows. As for Ubuntu, I was able to log in but any application I tried to start froze my operating system. But the data was visible. I took my PC to the technician who suggested changing the SSD as he said it broke. After that, he changed it for me and gave me the removed SSD.

To which I bought an interface (M.2 SATA to USBB 3.1 Gen. 1) to try to recover some data left over on the old SSD but unfortunately, upon connection, I am unable to see anything with my current Ubuntu version and working.

Could you kindly help me?

PS I also made an attempt to alter the order of the Bios, giving priority to the USB port, but the laptop cannot get it started. This worries me a lot because in any case, before taking it to the technician, at least I was able to start it even if it was unstable.

Comment: There is not Ubuntu 18. there is a 18.04

Comment: There are a number of connections to verify. USB port, cable, enclosure, drive seating in the enclosure... Have you verified each of these? Booting from it is overly ambitious at this stage and for your purpose (data recovery) not essential

Comment: This may be normal. Some external USB enclosures have a converter board that requires that you format the drive before it can be used. Once formatted, and data installed, it can not be returned to the host computer without another format. Connect the drive to another SATA port on the PC and you should be able to at least read what you could before.